# RecyclerView not updating list items fast enough

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-livedata

I have an App that is communicating with a meshNetwork and constantly receiving messages over wifi with the properties of meshNodes. Those nodes should be displayed in a `RecyclerView` and also updated when a property changes with the usage of `LiveData`.
However when I receive multiple messages at almost the same time, the RecyclerView does not update the list.
E.g. a message form a meshNode is received, if the node is not already in a list inside `LiveData<List<>>` it will be added. After adding it to the list, the bound recycler view displays the node, everything is perfect by now. Immediatly after a new message from another meshNode that is not in the list is received, and added to the list, the meshNode is not displayed in the RecyclerView.

I really dont know why, and every help will be appreciated.

`MeshNodeHandler` handles messages received from meshNetwork, and updating nodes list

```kotlin
class MeshNodeHandler() : MeshHandler.MeshListener() {
    private val mMeshNodes= mutableListOf<MeshNode>()
    private val mMeshNodesLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<MeshNode>> = MutableLiveData()
    val meshNodes: LiveData<List<MeshNode>>= mMeshNodesLiveData

    override fun onNodeMessageReceived(nodeMessage: NodeMessage) {
        val node =
            mMeshNodes.firstOrNull {
                it.meshID == nodeMessage.meshID
            }

        if (node != null && checkIfNodePropertiesChanged(node, nodeMessage)) {
            Timber.d("Update mesh node")
            // Update node in List...
            mMeshNodesLiveData.postValue(mMeshNodes)
        } else if (node == null) {
            Timber.d("Add mesh node")
            // Add node to list
            mMeshNodesLiveData.postValue(mMeshNodes)
        }
    }
}
```

`MeshNodesListViewModel` just exposing the list from the NodeHandler

```kotlin
class MeshNodesListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val meshNodeHandler: MeshNodeHandler
) : ViewModel() {
    val meshNodes: LiveData<List<MeshNode>> =  meshNodeHandler.meshNodes
}
```

And `MeshNodesListFragment` that observes the `LiveData` and submits the list to the adapter

```kotlin
class MeshNodesListFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentMeshNodesListBinding, MeshNodesListViewModel>(
    layoutId = R.layout.fragment_mesh_nodes_list
) {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewAdapter: MeshNodesAdapter

    override fun onInitDataBinding() {
        // DataBinding stuff ...
        viewBinding.meshNodesRecyclerView.apply {
            adapter = viewAdaper
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.meshNodes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { 
            Timber.d("Submit list")
            viewAdapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
D/MeshNodeHandler: Add mesh node
D/MeshNodesListFragment: Submit List
...
D/MeshNodehandler: Add mesh node
D/MeshNodesListFragment: Submit List
```

So the log says that a second node has been added to the `LiveData<List<>>`, and the list should also be submitted to the `Adaper`, but there is no second item displayed in the `RecyclerView`. If I destroy the `Fragment` and creating it again by switchig to portrait mode, then both items are displayed.

I'm thankful for every reply, cheers and stay healthy!

Comment: Are you using new ListAdapter or RecyclerView.Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you update the list. My understanding is that the list is updated but not reflecting in the view because recyclerView is not updating it's views. Try to call `notifyItemInserted()` or `notifyItemRangeInserted()` variants based on if you are adding single or multiple items. Hope this resolves the issue. Let me know if it helps.